# Find missing TLS Cipher

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, traefik

I'm running gitea behind a traefik proxy. Everything works fine except git push/pull to this git server. The http webfrontend is also working without problems.

As soon as i want to clone a repository, i get a `gnutls_handshake()` error. However, if i change the ciphers or switch to TLS 1.1, i have no problems. How do I find out the cipher that the git client (`version 2.30.2`) wants to use?

**OpenSSL version on clients (debian bullseye)**: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021

**Following ciphers are used by traefik:**

```
tls:
  options:
    default:
      minVersion: VersionTLS12
      cipherSuites:
        - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305
        - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305
      preferServerCipherSuites: true
      curvePreferences:
        - CurveP521
        - CurveP384
      sniStrict: true
```

**Output of gnutls-cli-debug:**

```
gnutls-cli-debug git.server.de
GnuTLS debug client 3.7.1
Checking git.server.de:443
whether the server accepts default record size (512 bytes)... yes
                  whether %ALLOW_SMALL_RECORDS is required... no
                        whether we need to disable TLS 1.2... no
                        whether we need to disable TLS 1.1... no
                        whether we need to disable TLS 1.0... no
                        whether %NO_EXTENSIONS is required... no
                             for TLS 1.0 (RFC2246) support... no
 for TLS 1.0 (RFC2246) support with TLS 1.0 record version... no
                             for TLS 1.1 (RFC4346) support... no
                                  fallback from TLS 1.1 to... failed
                             for TLS 1.2 (RFC5246) support... yes
                             for TLS 1.3 (RFC8446) support... no
                    for known TLS or SSL protocols support... yes
                       TLS1.2 neg fallback from TLS 1.6 to... failed (server requires fallback dance)
                                     for HTTPS server name... unknown
                               for certificate chain order... sorted
                  for safe renegotiation (RFC5746) support... yes
                    for encrypt-then-MAC (RFC7366) support... no
                   for ext master secret (RFC7627) support... no
                           for heartbeat (RFC6520) support... no
                       for version rollback bug in RSA PMS... yes
            whether the server ignores the RSA PMS version... yes
whether small records (512 bytes) are tolerated on handshake... yes
    whether cipher suites not in SSL 3.0 spec are accepted... yes
whether a bogus TLS record version in the client hello is accepted... yes
         whether the server understands TLS closure alerts... yes
            whether the server supports session resumption... yes
                      for anonymous authentication support... no
                              for RSA key exchange support... no
                      for ephemeral Diffie-Hellman support... no
                        for RFC7919 Diffie-Hellman support... no
                   for ephemeral EC Diffie-Hellman support... yes
for VKO GOST-2012 (draft-smyshlyaev-tls12-gost-suites) support... no
                             for curve SECP256r1 (RFC4492)... no
                             for curve SECP384r1 (RFC4492)... yes
                             for curve SECP521r1 (RFC4492)... yes
                                for curve X25519 (RFC8422)... no
                      for AES-GCM cipher (RFC5288) support... yes
                      for AES-CCM cipher (RFC6655) support... no
                    for AES-CCM-8 cipher (RFC6655) support... no
                      for AES-CBC cipher (RFC3268) support... no
                 for CAMELLIA-GCM cipher (RFC6367) support... no
                 for CAMELLIA-CBC cipher (RFC5932) support... no
                     for 3DES-CBC cipher (RFC2246) support... no
                  for ARCFOUR 128 cipher (RFC2246) support... no
            for CHACHA20-POLY1305 cipher (RFC7905) support... yes
for GOST28147-CNT cipher (draft-smyshlyaev-tls12-gost-suites) support... no
                                       for MD5 MAC support... no
                                      for SHA1 MAC support... no
                                    for SHA256 MAC support... no
for GOST28147-IMIT MAC (draft-smyshlyaev-tls12-gost-suites) support... no
                     for max record size (RFC6066) support... no
                for OCSP status response (RFC6066) support... no
```

Comment: Just sniff the first handshake message. The client's cipher suites are listed in the initial CLIENT_HELLO message.

Comment: @user207421: What is the best way to accomplish this?